# Recording JWT Refresh Times in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

I would like to record a datetime when users hit my `/jwt/auth` endpoint in Django. I am using Djoser and the `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` backend.

I tried to do this by extending the authentication backend like so:

```
class CustomAuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("hi mom")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        user = super().authenticate(request, username, password)
        try:    
            if user and user.is_authenticated:
                user.last_login = datetime.now()
                user.save()
            return user

        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

What's happening is that the `user` that is returned from `authenticate(...)` is `None` - so of course I don't get to enter my if statement.

My belief is that this is because the request I'm making is itself unauthenticated, since it's an auth request, even if somewhere in the process of getting a response, we do authenticate the user, or at least validate their JWT.

Where is the user actually referenced during this call to refresh? Can I piggyback off of that to make the user update that I want?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing here is decoding the jwt, which in our case did have a user ID in it. This feels inelegant to me, but it works:

```
user_id = jwt.decode(
                request.data["refresh"], algorithms=["HS256"], options=options
            )["user_id"]
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
```

The JWT can be pulled from the request.